# Limiting access to different user profile views

Tags: php, web-applications, yii, social-networking, access-control

For a social network style application, there are varying levels of access to user profiles, for instance, full profile (for owner), limited profile (profile owner friend), no access (random user).

How do I restrict the access to the different profile views (three in this case) using the Yii framework?

I have looked for this myself, but there's a confusing number of options available, some of which I'm not 100% sure would fit the above behavior. I suspect this is a bit of a noob question, so if this is well covered elsewhere please feel free to redirect me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be accessing user's profile using their id so you can check if the profile is of the current logged in user's profile and then in UsersController actionView you can do

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
   Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
}
if(Yii::app()->user->id == $user_id){
    //this is something to check before showing information about the current user. 
    //you can use this variable for some specific html blocks (to show them or not).
    $user_role = '1'; //full access
}
else {
    $user_role = '0'; //partial access
}
```

Though this is just a simple trick. There can be more sophisticated ways to do it.

Comment: This seems good to me, surprisingly simple. I've been reading about RBAC and optional Yii modules such as 'users' and 'rights', do you know if either of these cover the use cases I've outlined? If there are other options available, are you able to voice you opinion on the best options? I wanted to include this in the scope of my question, but the site warned me about being subjective. I'll still accept answers based on the way I've written the question above, if it's of concern.

Comment: The right way to redirect to the login URL is to call `Yii::app()->user->loginRequired()`. It will take care of going back to the current page automatically for you.

Comment: Goose: well IMO users' roles would apply for admin and normal user (really big difference in privileges for the whole web app) or in some special cases their could be others too (such as authors, readers etc.) but I don't think that will apply to your scenario as there is no need for having roles just to show specific data on a view page. You can make two view pages (myProfile and profile) just for the sake of keeping it abstract. Otherwise the way I've suggested should do the job too.

@MichaelHärtl: yeah that should be the way. thanks